# Pass command as variable to ECS task definition

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

Is there a way to pass a Docker command as a Terraform variable to the ECS task definition that is defined in Terraform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below method to take the `command` as a variable with template condition if nothing is passed from the root module. 
service.json

```
[
  {
    ...
    ],
    %{ if command != "" }
    "command"  : [${command}],
    %{ endif ~}
    ...
  }
]
```

container.tf

```
data "template_file" "container_def" {
  count    = 1
  template = file("${path.module}/service.json")
  vars = {
    command        = var.command != "" ? join(",", formatlist("\"%s\"", var.command)) : ""
  }
}
```

main.tf

```
module "example" {
...
     command                 = ["httpd", "-f", "-p", "8080"]
...
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "command" {
  default = ""
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`aws_ecs_task_definition` documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecs_task_definition.html), the [`container_definitions`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecs_task_definition.html#container_definitions) property is an unparsed JSON object that's an array of [container definitions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_ContainerDefinition.html) as you'd pass directly to the AWS APIs.  One of the properties of that object is a `command`.

Paraphrasing the documentation somewhat, you'd come up with a sample task definition like:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "service" {
  family                = "service"
  container_definitions = <<DEFINITIONS
[
  {
    "name": "first",
    "image": "service-first",
    "command": ["httpd", "-f", "-p", "8080"],
    "cpu": 10,
    "memory": 512,
    "essential": true
  }
]
DEFINITIONS
}
```

Comment: So how would I then pass a variable to a module that defined that?  For example, in my `variables.tf` I'd do something like:

```variable "command_arguments" {
  type = list(string)
  description = "The ecs task command arguments to run with ECS."
  default = []
}
```

But then how should the var be written and how should the definition accept the var?

Comment: Tried to declare in the `main.tf` to pass to module like this: `command_arguments = ["--env", var.env]`.  Then in the task definition be: ``` "command": "${length(var.command_arguments) == 0 ? "": "--env,dev" }",```    Did not work.